# How to reset scope which is created using template or schema change in Sync Framework?

Tags: sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a question in Sync Framework that

How we reset the scope in Sync Framework ?

There are some solutions that i found but they are working only when we use
PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc)

But i used FilterClause for that 
PopulateFromTemplate() method is used and for that the solutions 
are not working.

So anyone please if you have any solution then help me.

Answer (score 0):

For scopes that derive from a template, they do not have a separate scope definition. Rather, they simply reference the template's scope definition. You should modify the template then, not the scope.